# very long wit.ai response time

Tags: node.js, time, nlp, response, wit.ai

my question is about wit.ai response time
in case of my bot it takes about 50 seconds for phrase with 100 letters
is it not too long? i've also observed that during the morning, response is quicker than afternoon (Europe/Warsaw time zone). Any ideas?

Comment: time is relative if you don't provide anything real to work with. If it takes longer at certain times of the day, there is an X factor involved that we couldn't even possibly comment on correctly unless you actually provide something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting. Usually it's under 1sec so there is definitely an issue with your app. 
This may happen if you use keyword entities with a lot of values. Our algo is not optimized for this use case.